# Why don't PHP use a unit testing framework like PHPUnit?

Tags: php, unit-testing

I just stumbled upon a bug I found in PHP 5.5.11 where `substr_compare` isn't working properly given a certain combination of function parameters. ([Bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67043))

I was wondering how such a basic functionality like comparing strings can *ever* be broken in a released version of PHP. So I had a look into the official of PHP and took a look at the unit testing infrastructure.

The tests ([example](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/tests/strings/substr%5fcompare.phpt)) I had a look at are

- quite hard to read (as the instructions for the test and the assertions are separated you have to manually count the lines to know which assertions belong to which function calls) [sic]
- all of the assertions are based on string comparison (that's why all of the assertions are wrapped inside a `var_dump`) [sic]

So my questions are:

- Why don't PHP use a testing framework like PHPUnit? Are there any plans to migrate?
- Are there any stats about test coverage so one could find the lines of code which are not yet covered by a unit test?

Comment: Answer to your second question: http://gcov.php.net/

Comment: Note that PHP __does__ use a testing framework, but a different testing framework to PHPUnit

Comment: @MarkBaker I would definitely consider contributing some tests, yes.

Comment: @MarkBaker Haven't found this number during my research - thanks. But how would I find the lines of code in PHP which lack of unit testing coverage?

Comment: @MarkBaker Which testing framework do you rely on? Are there tests for this testing framework like i.e. [PHPUnit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/tree/master/tests) has?

Comment: Finding the lines of code that aren't covered is easy: follow the link I posted, select your version, select the file you want to check and look for the blue and orange background colours - e.g. http://gcov.php.net/PHP_5_5/lcov_html/ext/spl/spl_dllist.c.gcov.php

Comment: And it's also fairly easy to write tests for PHP.... fork PHP, write your tests and submit a PR.... there's a few of my tests in there - the dlllist add() method in the page I linked on gcov.php.net for example (though the code for that method is mine as well) and I also wrote some of the tests for the zipArchive class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is currently using `phpt` for testing.

Using something bigger like PHPUnit would include too much php logic into the tests. Meaning a bug in PHP could PHPUnit let a test pass which would fail otherwise. Note that PHP itself should be tested but PHPUnit is written in PHP.

But however, even the `run-tests.php` which is required to run the current tests uses ~2600 lines of PHP code. Meaning a bug in the functions used there could influence the test results, but the amount of complexity is still much less than with PHPUnit.

I hope your other questions are well answered by the comments of @MarkBaker. Maybe this link provides some additional information: https://qa.php.net/write-test.php

Remains to say, PHP is open source software and you are free to improve the test suite. In your special case, the `substr_compare` bug, I would encourage you to do that.

Comment: I was a little too late, this bug has already been fixed and some tests were added. That's the reason I was asking about how to find the lines of code which lack of test coverage.

Comment: Are there tests for `phpt` like i.e. PHPUnit has?

Comment: I just found out, that there **is** a per line code-coverage report online: http://gcov.php.net/PHP_HEAD/lcov_html/

Comment: Is it really an argument that "it would include too much php logic into the tests"? Let's say PHP code is 100% tested. Then it wouldn't matter that the testing logic is built on top of PHP since it would verify itself. This is only true for the PHP function library, verifying the PHP compiler is not possible using this approach.

Comment: `Let's say PHP code is 100% tested. ... since it would verify itself` This makes no sense (imo).